# How can I automatically skip certain JUnit tests based on a condition?

Tags: java, junit, junit-rule

I would like a simple way to assign a priority value to my JUnit tests such that I can say 'run only priority 1 tests', 'run priority 1, 2 and 3 tests' etc. I am aware that I could just include a line like `Assume.assumeTrue("Test skipped for priority " + priority, priority <= 2);` at the start of each test (where `priority` is the highest value priority tests I want to run and `2` is the priority value of this particular test), however copy-pasting a line at the start of each test doesn't seem a very good solution.

I have tried writing a solution using a simple annotation which is detected by the JUnit Rule I am using anyway:

```
public class Tests {
    @Rule
    public TestRules rules = new TestRules();
    @Test
    @Priority(2)
    public void test1() {
        // perform test
    }
}

public class TestRules extends TestWatcher {
    private int priority = 1; // this value is manually changed to set the priority of tests to run
    @Override
    protected void starting(Description desc) {
        Priority testCasePriority = desc.getAnnotation(Priority.class);
        Assume.assumeTrue("Test skipped for priotity " + priority, testCasePriority == null || testCasePriority.value() <= priority);
    }
}

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Priority {
    public int value() default 0;
}
```

While this appears to work (the correct tests are shown as skipped in the Eclipse JUnit view) the tests are still performed, i.e. any code in `test1()` is still run.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get the `Assume` in my Rule to actually skip the test?

Comment: This might help :-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689242/conditionally-ignoring-tests-in-junit-4

Comment: ... or this might help: http://www.codeaffine.com/2013/11/18/a-junit-rule-to-conditionally-ignore-tests/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception thrown by a `TestWatcher.starting` are ignored, and rethrown at the end of the test.

You should implement a `TestRule` instead of a `TestWatcher` :

```
public class TestRules implements TestRule {
    private int priority = 1; // this value is manually changed to set the priority of tests to run

     public Statement apply(final Statement base, final Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                Priority testCasePriority = desc.getAnnotation(Priority.class);
                Assume.assumeTrue("Test skipped for priotity " + priority, testCasePriority == null || testCasePriority.value() <= priority);

                base.evaluate();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I have other `starting()`, `failed()` and `finished()` methods in my `TestWatcher` subclass, are these simple to recreate in a `TestRule` or is it worth creating a separate `TestRule` for my `Assume` method in addition to my existing `TestWatcher` subclass?

Comment: look at the source of TestWatcher : it's just a simple delegating implementation of a TestRule. You can easily reimplements your TestWatcher from a TestRule : https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.java